# Invalid hotkey: Ctrl & CapsLock & L

Tags: autohotkey

To map `CapsLock` to `Esc` if pressed alone, and use it as a modifier key otherwise, I use this script:

```
#InstallKeybdHook
SetCapsLockState AlwaysOff
CapsLock::Send {esc}
CapsLock & h::Left
CapsLock & j::Down
CapsLock & k::Up
CapsLock & l::Right
return
```

To move around virtual desktops in Windows, I wanted to now map `Ctrl & CapsLock & l::^#Right`. Unfortunately this is not possible and gives an error: `Invalid hotkey`. Does anybody know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of remapping I'd use the [Send](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm) command to define new hotkeys.
A remapping is not a hotkey. A remapping is two hotkeys (key-down and key-up) with each having the wildcard modifier, as shown in the [documentation](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Remap.htm#remarks).

[Combinations of three or more keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#combo) (Ctrl & CapsLock & l) are not supported.
Or try it this way:

```
#InstallKeybdHook
SetCapsLockState AlwaysOff

CapsLock::Send {esc}
CapsLock & h::Send {Left}
CapsLock & j::Send {Down}
CapsLock & k::Send {Up}

CapsLock & l::
If GetKeyState("Ctrl", "P")
    SendEvent {LWin down}{LCtrl down}{Right down}{LWin up}{LCtrl up}{Right up}    ; switch to next virtual desktop
else
    Send {Right}
return
```

Comment: Thank you so much. For me the script also works with `SetKeyDelay -1`.